Publisher changes page size when exporting to pdf
I created a document in Microsoft Publisher on a custom size paper, but when I exported it to PDF, it automatically changed the paper size to A4.


Did you select the correct paper size when you printed the pdf? Publisher likely choose a paper size for you.

I didnt print it, I just Exported it to PDF.

IF you were using the "convert" that is shown in the toolbar, don't - try going to the FILE tab, then SAVE AS, and change the type to PDF. I routinely do this, and have never had the paper size change.

No the image is the PDF, I used export, & I tried using F12 (save as) as you suggested but that didnt make any difference.

@ES - You still printed or exported the document, which means you still "created" a PDF file. You should have been prompted to select a document or page size.

When exporting the file, click the "Options" button

then select "Print options"

then this window will appear where you can change the page size


Please take the time to [edit] this answer and provide specific detailed instructions on what resolved your issue.  The linked response is a generic, useless copy-and-paste response. We want a lot more detail than the response provided.
